# How to only allow one user connection alive at the same time with Nodejs and Expressjs?

Tags: node.js, express, websocket, express-session, nestjs

I just need to manage the concurrence on my app built with **nodejs** on the top of the nestjs framework.

As a far as I know, the most simplest way to do that is controlling that online **one session user** in **expressjs** is alive.

I am not taking care about security or whatever other issues, just want to know **how many users are connected** and restricting it to **only one user session** till **its session is expired**.

Here is my codebase

```
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
var app = express();

var numConnections = 0;


app.use(session({
    cookieName: 'sessionTest',
    secret: 'eg[isfd-8yF9-7w2315df{}+Ijsli;;to8', 
    cookie: {
      secure: false,
      maxAge: 1000 * 10,
      sameSite: true
    }
}));


app.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.session.store)
    console.log(req.session.ip)
    console.log(req.session.useragent)
    console.log(req.connection.remoteAddress)
    console.log(req.headers['user-agent'])
    if (numConnections === 0 
        // && req.session
        ) {
        req.session.ip = req.connection.remoteAddress;
        req.session.useragent = req.headers['user-agent'];
        req.session.page_views = 1;
        res.send("Welcome to this page for the first time!");
        numConnections++;
        console.log(req.session);
        next();
    }
    else if (numConnections == 1 &&
        req.session.ip === req.connection.remoteAddress
        && req.session.useragent === req.headers['user-agent']
    ) {
        req.session.page_views++;
        res.send("You visited this page " + req.session.page_views + " times");
        console.log('TEST');
        next();
    } else {
        console.log('There is someone using the app!!!');
        return res.sendStatus(401);
    }

})

app.listen(3001);
```

I really appreciate if someone can help me

Answer (score 0):

You could use the store to retrieve the current amount of open sessions. The [doc](https://github.com/expressjs/session#session-store-implementation) says stores *may* implement `length` and/or `all` methods. However, it appears that only the default `MemoryStore` handles these. You can look at all the compatible store implementations at the bottom of the page and pick the one that fits your environment.

It *probably* (i.e. not tested) looks like this:

```
var session = require('express-session');
var memoryStoreThatWillBeChangedBeforeLiveEnvironment = new MemoryStore();
...
app.use(session({
  ...
  store: memoryStoreThatWillBeChangedBeforeLiveEnvironment
}));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  memoryStoreThatWillBeChangedBeforeLiveEnvironment.length((err, size) => {
    if (err) return res.status(418).send("I'm a teapot");
    var numConnections = size;
    // call your code here
  })
});
```

(Quite obviously, if an implementation only offers the `all` method, you can count the returned array of sessions.)